# how to measure in width of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to keep  % width gap  between two HTML elements.

Is there any tool which could tell  gap in %  ?

I checked Measure IT  tool  ....but  it shows in pixel ...not in %.

What is the solution ?

**EDIT:**  I  want to keep TD  width in % ...not in pixel  .....but I am confused how big width I should set ..so  visually I want to see the width first and then I want to put width in TD.

What should I do ?  Any tool can help on this ?

Any firefox plugin can help on this ? I have Measure IT firefox plugin installed ...but this shows width in pixel ....not in %

Comment: In `%` relative to what? You'll always need a reference width. When you know that, you can calculate the percent from the pixels

Comment: width in % == 100 * width in pixels / width of window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it gonna look something like that using jQuery

```
var element_w = $('.your_html_element').width()
var page_w = $('body').width()
var padding_w = e_w * 100 / page_w

$('.your_html_element').css('padding-left',padding_w+'px')
```